# Testing methods with callback parameters

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a method that is passed a callback parameter so that when some data inside of the method is set, it will call the callback function.

The method looks like: 
`myService.updateData(callback);`, and when I call it, `myService.updateData(function() { // do things after data has been set });`

How would I, in a Jasmine test, test the stuff that would happen when the callback was executed?

Would it be possible to do something like

`spyOn(myService, 'updateData').and.callFake(function() {});` ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to test `myService.updateData` or the callback itself? If the former, then what actual impact does the callback have - can you just ignore it by putting in some dummy function - e.g. no-op or something that just returns a constant result?

Comment: @vlaz, I am trying to test the callback itself. The callback notifies me of when some data inside of the `updateData` method has been set. But now thinking about it, what if I were to just set that data beforehand on the component. Something like, `component.data = []`. Then I can make my assertions right?

Comment: That's the idea - if you don't actually care about the callback in your test, then substitute it with a dummy one and just focus on the function at hand.

Comment: @vlaz What if I wanted to execute the callback and test what happens inside of it?

Comment: Then that is a separate test. You will extract the callback somewhere something like `myCallback = function() { /* whatever */ }`, so it is not just passed inline - you will be calling `myService.updateData(myCallback)` and you will have some way of exposing it for testing purposes. Then write a test for the `myCallback` function. Remember, in unit tests it's important to focus on ideally one thing at a time. This makes it easy to isolate what went wrong. If you're testing both `updateData` and the callback, a problem with either will fail the test, so you will need to investigate both.